# How to change the config file in TravisCI to run Django?

Tags: django, travis-ci

I am new to TravisCI and have written the following text in .travis.yml:

```
language: python

python:
  - 3.6

env:
  - DJANGO=2.0.2

script: 
 - python manage.py test
```

I am trying to run a build for a Django-project. The build runs, but for some reason it fails because TravisCI thinks it is a Ruby-project. This is not strange as, when I press "view config", I see that it is written for Ruby (also see screenshot below):

```
{
  "language": "ruby",
  "group": "stable",
  "dist": "trusty",
  "os": "linux"
}
```

[image]

Does anyone know how to change this config-file to fit for Django? So that my .travis.yml file can run correctly?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ndarville/3625246

Comment: Thanks! I tried using that website, but removed some of the fields like "before_install" and "install", but maybe I need to have them all, I will try that :)